# how to pass query param in graphql

Tags: reactjs, graphql

Is that possible to pass data inside the body query in graphql??  Like this

```
    var name = formData.get('name');
    var email = formData.get('email');
    var message = formData.get('message');

    const resp = await fetch('/graphql', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            query: '{createPost (name: '+ name +' , email: '+ email +' , message: '+ message +') {id, statut}}',

        }),
        credentials: 'include',
    });
    const { data } = await resp.json();
    if (!data || !data.createPost) throw new Error('Error');

    console.log(data.createPost)
```

In the query line i want to pass all the var that i get from a submit form.
When i try this , i got this error

```
{


"errors": [
    {
      "message": "Syntax Error GraphQL request (1:29) Expected :, found Name \"email\"\n\n1: {createPost(name: John Doe , email: JD@test.com , message: blablabla) {id, statut}}\n                               ^\n",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 1,
          "column": 29
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 3):

Use [variables](https://facebook.github.io/graphql/#sec-Language.Variables) to compose your queries, avoid string building. You get type checks for free!

I'm not well-versed in javascript, but I believe this will work:

```
var name = formData.get('name');
var email = formData.get('email');
var message = formData.get('message');

const resp = await fetch('/graphql', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        query: 'query Q($name: String, $email: String, $message: String){createPost (name: $name, email: $email, message: $message) {id, statut}}',
        variables: {
          name: name,
          email: email,
          message: message
        }

    }),
    credentials: 'include',
});
const { data } = await resp.json();
if (!data || !data.createPost) throw new Error('Erreur sur l`envoi du message !');

console.log(data.createPost)
```

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me;

```
const graphqlQuery = `{
      products {
        id
        title
        images
      }
    }`

const params = encodeURI(graphqlQuery)

fetch('http://localhost:3001/?raw&query=' + params, {
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": 'text/plain'
  }
}).then(function(response) {
  console.log('response', response);
  return response.json()
})
```